# control class treatment progress from another class

Tags: c#, queue

i hope i get sucess my explanation.

I am designing a console application for a POC software (proof of concept) with minimal functionnalities as follow :

```
[Class 1]
1- Timer run each 60 seconds.
2- download an xml file over http (WebClient)
3- parse IDs (ID of metadata xml file inside the same http server)
4- Enqueue the queue by IDs in Class 2 [Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>()]
[Class 2 ]
5- Dequeue urls and start download each file whithin teh queue
6- Deserialize the xml to a valid reference an d save it into Database
```

Question :

How can i tell the timer in Class1 to escape treatement if download of files in Class2 is still in progress (can take more time than Timer peridicity interval).

N.B : download is asynchronosly.

Regards

Comment: If you want it that way, don't do it 'asynchronous'.

Answer (score 0):

You can still download asynchronously but you should treat the downloading as a state machine ...Busy/Idle.

When your timer raises the interval event, check whether the 'machine' is Idle. If so, fire up another download.

...make sense?

Comment: ye make sense but i'am asking about where storing suchc information , i wan't achive that by using static variable. Thnaks